# How to fetch all images from internal storage through file api

Tags: image, file, duplicates, fetch, internal-storage

how to fetch all images from internal storage through the file api?

I have done it, but only from a specific folder?

```
fun findimage( scanningFiles: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>, file: File ): HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> {  
    arraylist = ArrayList()
    val files = file.listFiles()
    if (files != null) {
        for (f in files) {
            if (f.isDirectory && !f.isHidden) {
                findimage(scanningFiles, f)
            } else {
                when (f.mimeType()?.substringBefore("/")) {
                    "image/*" -> {
                        /*return f.path*/
                        val md5 = getFileChecksum(f)

                        /*return md5*/
                        var fs: ArrayList<String>
                        if (!scanningFiles.containsKey(md5)) {
                            fs = ArrayList()
                            scanningFiles[md5] = fs
                        }
                        fs = scanningFiles[md5]!!
                        fs.add(f.path)
                        fs.sortWith { lhs, rhs -> lhs.length - rhs.length }
                        Log.d("hhhh", "huuhhuh" + fs.size)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return scanningFiles
}

fun displayimg() {
    val scanningFiles: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> = HashMap()
    val path=findimage(scanningFiles,File(Constant.PARENT_DIR_PATH))

    Log.d("MainActivity", "displayimg: $path")
}

object Constant {
    const val PARENT_DIR_PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/"
}
```

Comment: What programming language is that? please add necessary data.

Comment: its kotlin language